# Sum of Bernoulli random variables and its limit

Tags: probability

Let$\ X_1,...,X_n$ be independent Bernoulli random variables with parameter$\ p_i$, then for any$\ ε$:

$\ P(|\frac{X_1+...+X_n}{n} -p(n)| ≤ ε) \longrightarrow 1 $ as $\ n\to\infty$

With $\ p(n)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n p_i$

What I've done:

For every i, it's known that$\ E(X_i)=p_i$ and$\ Var(X_i)=p_i(1-p_i)$, so

$\ E(\frac{X_1+...+X_n}{n})=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n p_i$ and $\ Var(\frac{X_1+...+X_n}{n})=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n p_i(1-p_i)$

I'm stuck at this point, what can I use to get the result?

Comment: What does "identical" mean in the first line?

Comment: Yeah, my mistake, they're independent

Comment: Also there should be an $n^2$ in the basement of the variance.

Comment: Also it should either be $\to 0$ in the second line or $\le \epsilon.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we let $\overline X_n \equiv \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$  then we have $$ E(\overline X_n) = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n p_i\\ \operatorname{Var}(\overline X_n) = \frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{i=1}^np_i(1-p_i).$$

Chebyshev gives $$ P\left(\left|\overline X_n-\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n p_i\right| \ge \epsilon\right) \le \frac{\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{i=1}^np_i(1-p_i)}{\epsilon^2}\le \frac{1}{n\epsilon^2}.$$

Comment: But, in the last inequality, if n goes to ∞, it converges to 0, isn't it?

Comment: @DavidTomahak Yes but notice I have a $\ge \epsilon$ inside the $P$

Comment: Yeah, thanks for the help, I just have to use that$\ P(|X -μ| <ϵ) ≥1 - σ^2/ϵ^2$